# Diagnosing and parsing the output of matplotlib.test()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just installed the latest stable version of `matplotlib (1.2.1)` on a fresh Python installation (2.7.4) with the latest stable version `IPython (0.13.2)`.

I run `matplotlib.test()` and the final result was the following:

## Summary of matplotlib.test()

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1251 tests in 857.869s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=312, SKIP=3, failures=2)
/home/avazquez/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1033: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)
Out[2]: False
```

How should I interpret this message? Did `matplotlib` installation failed the test?

In case it helps, below is the more verbose output:

## Running matplotlib.test()

```
In [1]: import matplotlib

In [2]: matplotlib.test()
....K...K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K...K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K...K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K...K.SSS.K..............K..K..K..K..K..K..KK.................................................................K....K....K...K..K..K.K..KK....K..K..K..K......................................................................................................................................................................................K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K..K........K.......K...K..K..K..K..K..K...K..K..K.....K..K.....

/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1224: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1234: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=14.0. Returning /opt/Python-2.7.3-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf
  UserWarning)
/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1234: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=bold:stretch=500:size=14.0. Returning /opt/Python-2.7.3-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf
  UserWarning)
/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1224: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['sans serif'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1234: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=italic:variant=normal:weight=750:stretch=500:size=14.0. Returning /opt/Python-2.7.3-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf
  UserWarning)
/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1234: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=200:stretch=500:size=14.0. Returning /opt/Python-2.7.3-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf
  UserWarning)
/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1234: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=500:stretch=100:size=14.0. Returning /opt/Python-2.7.3-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf
  UserWarning)
FFK..K.......K..K..K..K..K/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/gridspec.py:298: UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so its results might be incorrect.
  warnings.warn("This figure includes Axes that are not "
..K..K.........................K....KK
======================================================================
FAIL: matplotlib.tests.test_text.test_font_styles.test
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/testing/decorators.py", line 39, in failer
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/testing/decorators.py", line 158, in do_test
    '(RMS %(rms).3f)'%err)
ImageComparisonFailure: images not close: /nfs/drive5/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/result_images/test_text/font_styles.png vs. /nfs/drive5/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/result_images/test_text/font_styles-expected.png (RMS 47.353)

======================================================================
FAIL: matplotlib.tests.test_text.test_font_styles.test
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/testing/decorators.py", line 39, in failer
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/testing/decorators.py", line 158, in do_test
    '(RMS %(rms).3f)'%err)
ImageComparisonFailure: images not close: /nfs/drive5/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/result_images/test_text/font_styles_pdf.png vs. /nfs/drive5/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/result_images/test_text/font_styles-expected_pdf.png (RMS 23.423)
```

and here is the part of the installation log:

## Installing matplotlib from a virtualenv:

```
$ pip install matplotlib
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-1.2.1.tar.gz (38.4MB): 38.4MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package matplotlib
    basedirlist is: ['/usr/local', '/usr']
    ============================================================================
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: 1.2.1
                    python: 2.7.4 (default, Apr 21 2013, 18:37:10)  [GCC 4.1.2
                            20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)]
                  platform: linux2

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                     numpy: 1.7.1
                 freetype2: 9.10.3

    OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                    libpng: 1.2.10
                   Tkinter: no
                            * Using default library and include directories for
                            * Tcl and Tk because a Tk window failed to open.
                            * You may need to define DISPLAY for Tk to work so
                            * that setup can determine where your libraries are
                            * located. Tkinter present, but header files are not
                            * found. You may need to install development
                            * packages.
                      Gtk+: no
                            * Building for Gtk+ requires pygtk; you must be able
                            * to "import gtk" in your build/install environment
           Mac OS X native: no
                        Qt: no
                       Qt4: no
                    PySide: no
                     Cairo: no

    OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
                  dateutil: matplotlib will provide
                      pytz: matplotlib will provide

    OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: 1.5
               ghostscript: 8.70
                     latex: 3.141592
                   pdftops: 3.00

    [Edit setup.cfg to suppress the above messages]
    ============================================================================
    pymods ['pylab']
    packages ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor', 'matplotlib.projections', 'matplotlib.testing', 'matplotlib.testing.jpl_units', 'matplotlib.tests', 'mpl_toolkits', 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1', 'mpl_toolkits.axisartist', 'matplotlib.sphinxext', 'matplotlib.tri', 'matplotlib.delaunay', 'pytz', 'dateutil', 'dateutil.zoneinfo']

    warning: no files found matching 'KNOWN_BUGS'
    warning: no files found matching 'INTERACTIVE'
    warning: no files found matching 'make.osx'
    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching '__init__.py'
    warning: no files found matching 'examples/data/*'
    warning: no files found matching 'lib/mpl_toolkits'
    warning: no files found matching 'lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlib.conf'
    warning: no files found matching 'lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlib.conf.template'
    warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 16: 'recursive-include' expects <dir> <pattern1> <pattern2> ...

    warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE*' under directory 'license'
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
  Running setup.py install for matplotlib
    basedirlist is: ['/usr/local', '/usr']
    ============================================================================
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: 1.2.1
                    python: 2.7.4 (default, Apr 21 2013, 18:37:10)  [GCC 4.1.2
                            20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)]
                  platform: linux2

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                     numpy: 1.7.1
                 freetype2: 9.10.3

    OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                    libpng: 1.2.10
                   Tkinter: no
                            * Using default library and include directories for
                            * Tcl and Tk because a Tk window failed to open.
                            * You may need to define DISPLAY for Tk to work so
                            * that setup can determine where your libraries are
                            * located. Tkinter present, but header files are not
                            * found. You may need to install development
                            * packages.
                      Gtk+: no
                            * Building for Gtk+ requires pygtk; you must be able
                            * to "import gtk" in your build/install environment
           Mac OS X native: no
                        Qt: no
                       Qt4: no
                    PySide: no
                     Cairo: no

    OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
                  dateutil: matplotlib will provide
                      pytz: matplotlib will provide

    OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: 1.5
               ghostscript: 8.70
                     latex: 3.141592
                   pdftops: 3.00

    [Edit setup.cfg to suppress the above messages]
    ============================================================================
    pymods ['pylab']
    packages ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor', 'matplotlib.projections', 'matplotlib.testing', 'matplotlib.testing.jpl_units', 'matplotlib.tests', 'mpl_toolkits', 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1', 'mpl_toolkits.axisartist', 'matplotlib.sphinxext', 'matplotlib.tri', 'matplotlib.delaunay', 'pytz', 'dateutil', 'dateutil.zoneinfo']
```

#### TKinter?

Also I am surprised that the installation of matplotlib reports `Tkinter: No`. I can import `Tkinter` in `IPython`:

```
In [1]: import Tkinter
In [2]: _tkinter.TK_VERSION
Out [2]: '8.5'
In [3]: Tkinter.__version__
Out[3]: '$Revision: 81008 $'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to disregard those two failures.

Those test are, um, finicky. They fail on master on some of my machines and seem to pass on Travis. If you want to see exactly what failed look in  `/nfs/drive5/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/result_images/test_text/` and compare `font_styles.png` and `font_styles-expected_pdf.png`.  I strongly suspect it will be fonts shifted by a few pixels.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know by any chance by matplot lib reports `Tkinter: No` (see my 3rd log) when in fact I can load the module correctly (4th log)

Comment: the build log suggests you don't have the headers available

Comment: Thanks tcaswell. That's a great point. I actually have built tcl and tk manually and have the headers. How can I tell matplotlib where they are?

Comment: I think I found it: `"If you have installed prerequisites to nonstandard places and need to inform matplotlib where they are, edit setupext.py and add the base dirs to the basedir dictionary entry for your sys.platform. e.g., if the header to some required library is in /some/path/include/someheader.h, put /some/path in the basedir list for your platform."` from http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html

Comment: @user815423426 That is a generic `setup.py`/`virtualenv` question, not specific to `matplotlib` (which I don't know the answer to).  I suspect you just need to play with the the paths.